# How to filter acoustic signal

Tags: filtering

I have a huge data file which I can't ListPlot.

This code generates similar kind of data:

```
datatest =RandomSample[Join[RandomReal[{0.5, 15}, 20], RandomReal[.1, 10000]]];
datatest2 = 5 + Riffle[datatest, -datatest];
```

I want to filter (delete) the part of the data that is not necessary as follows:

```
peaks = FindPeaks[datatest2, 0, 0, 5.2];
ListPlot[datatest2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[peaks]}]
```

[image]
Currently I am using some kind of long way to do the task.

Is there  any signal processing functionality in MMA that can do this easily?

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand. Isn't the output of `FindPeaks` exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: I want to keep the peaks and some data around. In another  word I want to delete the marked parts in the plot.

Comment: I have more than 1 Billion data point which I can't visualize. most of the data is similar to the parts marked in the plot. I want to delete these parts so that I can visualize the data

Comment: I think `FindPeaks[]` is the best way to do this.  If it is taking too long, split `datatest2` into $k$ equal portions (e.g., $k=8$ or $16$) and then `Parallelize[]` your `FindPeaks[]` operation.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear (squiggly marks on a graph is not a substitute for a precise specification) but this previous question seems related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22528/484

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert (understatemnt of the year!) in signal processing but you can use the band function and create a sparse matrix that has as many 1s as you want around the positions of the peaks. I am not sure the following is the best way to do this but it works:

```
With[{width = 200},
  spArray = SparseArray[
    Thread[
     (Band[# - width, # + width] & /@ peaks[[All, 1]]) -> 1], 
    Length[datatest2]]
  ];
```

so this means that I have made a sparse array with 1s in 400 samples ($\pm 200$) around each of your peaks and if I multiply this with your original array `dataset2` these are gonna be the only elements that will survive:

```
ListPlot[spArray datatest2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[peaks]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good approach however the number of points still the same which is the main problem. you can image how impossible to plot data contains 1 Billion point. I will think of way to remove those zeros without affecting the zeros around the peaks. thanks

Comment: This will do the job: pos = Flatten[Position[Normal[spArray], 1]];
datatest2[[pos]];

Comment: @Algohi I don't quite understand what the connection is between the filter and the plotting bit. If you need to plot, why not use the method I posted and subsample the resulting array. Is it billions of data with only a few peaks or with millions of peaks? I am sure we (SE) think of something if you re edit to clarify the question a bit

Comment: It is billion with hundreds of peaks. when I said filter I did not know what the correct word is. that is why I add delete after. I hope this clarify the issue and sorry for any ambiguity:)

Comment: @Algohi, I didn't mean it in a frustrated way :) - and by no means don't feel pressured to accept if it's not working - but there's a few things I don't understand still. Does `FindPeaks` work at all with your data? I would doubt that it does with a billion points. So do you know where the peaks are? Do you know how many there are if not? If you don't that's a (difficult) question in itself: "how to find hundreds of peaks among billions of points?".

Comment: Not at all, your answer is ok for me. For your other concerns, you are right, I can't find the peaks and even open the big file in MMA. I have asked this question before (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72984/how-to-efficiently-read-data-from-any-part-inside-huge-file). I found a way to do that by reading part from the big file and then find the peaks and then remove the unnecessary data and then read the another part of the big file and find peaks and delete unnecessary data and so on. the file after doing this reduced from around 5 G to 20 MB.

Comment: The final result is here http://s3.postimg.org/q5rw8ue6r/Untitled.jpg and here
http://s29.postimg.org/v3vee4kmv/Untitled.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you need, but here's my try: If you want to keep only `2d+1` data points around each peak, you can use

```
toKeep = Map[# + Range[-d, d] &, peaks[[All, 1]]];
choppedData = Map[Part[datatest2, #] &, toKeep];
```

`choppedData` is a list of lists, the `i`-th list contains the `2d+1` values around the `i`-th peak.

To speed up you can use `ParallelMap` instead of `Map`.

Comment: Thanks but note here that, peaks[[;;,1]] does not necessary to be Integer number. you may add Floor or Ceiling. Second, there will be intersection if d is larger than the minimum distance between peaks. This will create additional work to do. Any way thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to remove outliers is with the Median filter. What you want to do is the opposite: to keep the outliers and remove the inliers. Subtracting the data from the median, then clipping the result and selecting all those larger than a threshold is one way to proceed.

```
short = Select[Chop[datatest2 - MedianFilter[datatest2, 5], 0.5], Abs[#] > 0.1 &]; 
ListPlot[short, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

One downside is that this removes the mean value (about five in your data). You may wish to add this back in, and also to fiddle with the parameters to get the width you are looking for.