# How can I monitor the progress of a Plot?

Tags: plotting, monitoring

The answer in [How to monitor the progress of a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37922) is not useful in my case.

I am using

```
ListLogLogPlot[{Thread[{bigListX, bigList2}], Thread[{ssfPos, PSDPos2}]},
  PlotRange -> All]
```

The problem is that those lists are really big, around $200 \times 10^6$  points. 
I would like to see the progress of the plotting. I want *Mathematica* to tell me "where" it is at the moment.

Comment: The title does not match the content, imo.

Comment: In my opinion, it is not reasonable to draw a figure with 200 million points on. Normally, these kind of problem can be represented by sampling the dataset. Drawing 200 million points in a 6 inch by 4 inch square is not a very useful for visualizing your data.

Comment: Moreover, in Plot time is spent on recursion/sampling the domain, here not. Mostly on rendering, it takes a lot due to the sample size. Now you would like to interrupt it at each point and show it somewhere which means you want to plot 200kk plots with sample sizes from 1 to 200kk...

Comment: You are absolutely right...

Comment: But anyway, what is the way to monitor a plot which takes some time?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22528)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. no reference to `MaxPlotPoints` either here or in the other thread? I am not sure what approach it uses, so maybe it is not as sophisticated as the methods shown there, but the results are virtually the same. Is this a particularly obscure option?

Comment: @Oleksandr it has [been mentioned 48 times so far](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=MaxPlotPoints) on this site so it's not too esoteric at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Mr. Wizard's  suggestions, I'll offer the following comment to the OP's situation in an attempt to summarize the communal wisdom on this point.

The great difficulty in the OP's question is in **timing the *rendering* process**, which takes place in the Front End and vastly overshadows the calculation time in the original problem. **Unfortunately, there is no (documented/known) way to do that so far**.

I also think, however, that the whole point may be moot. If the situation is such that rendering overshadows computation, then one should consider **pruning the data set** being plotted because it is likely to be too detailed to be meaningfully presented at common resolutions and sizes, as kettern also mentioned.

In this connection, one can make judicious use of the `MaxPlotPoints` option for the list plotting functions to **downsample** such a data set automatically ([its documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxPlotPoints.html) states that "the total number of points plotted is reduced by combining nearby points"). Oleksandr and Mr. Wizard mentioned it in comments as well.

Comment: Marco, I encouraged you to post this and I still believe it is a valid and important point.  However in brief testing it seems the situation has changed between versions 7 and 10.1.  In version 7 `ListPlot` evaluates very quickly.  In 10.1 it is *much* slower, greatly surpassing rendering time.  I shall explore this tomorrow if I have time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No worries: I had not done any testing myself, nor do I have older versions at hand, so I had not noticed. That would be interesting to see, if you get round to it. If it turns out to be a different problem altogether, I can always remove / update my answer.

Comment: It seems that only in certain cases such as multiple data sets is `ListPlot` generation slow.  I posted a [new question about it.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84739/121)

Comment: Could you have a look at this question as well^^ ? [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84835/monitor-progress-of-a-function-fourier-in-my-case)

Answer (score -2):

```
 Monitor[ListLogLogPlot[Table[{n, y = n RandomReal[]}, {n, 1, 10^5}]], 
 ProgressIndicator[y, {1, 10^5}]]
```

Comment: David, this may not work as you intended. The indicator seems to show progress as numbers are generated, but the rendering of those points by the plotting function, which is the part that takes the longest, is not captured.

Comment: @MarcoB  Try the new solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the progress indicator is now meaningless, since it is literally fed a random value. It will stop at a point indicated by the last random number that was generated, which may be at the beginning, in the middle, or at the end, by random chance. It will then pause there while rendering happens. This behavior may be more clear if you try with an upper limit of 10^6.

Comment: I think that the great difficulty in this question is timing the *rendering* process, which vastly overshadows the calculation time in these examples, and in the OP's original problem. I think, however, that the whole point may be moot. If the situation is such that rendering overshadows computation, then one should consider pruning the data set being plotted because it's simply too detailed.

Comment: @MarcoB I think you should make that an answer, because IMHO it is the best one available.  I think only an undocumented hook in the Front End that gives a progress monitor on rendering would do any good here.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OK I will, thank you for the suggestion.