# Monitor Progress of a function (Fourier[] in my case)

Tags: fourier-analysis, monitoring

I am using

```
PSD = Abs[Fourier[normedAutoValues, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]];
```

`normedAutoValues` contains around 200 *10^7 data points.

So it takes for ever... Is there a way to monitor the progress of `Fourier[]`?

Comment: If you have so much data on hand, you might want to look into implementing a pruned FFT.

Comment: You might also consider using `Spectrogram`, which nicely partitions the data and takes the spectra in reasonably sized chunks. If what you want is the PSD (power spectral density), as suggested by your variable name, then a single FFT is not the way to do it. You might want to consider `PowerSpectralDensity` .

Comment: In my case it is the PSD, because the data is already the autocorrelation of the signal. Thanks for the tip with Spectrogram. I will try that.

Comment: Why do you need so much points? How about resampling the data? Do you really need to capture such high components of the FFT?